# Is it possible to block the SMS notification with SMS Retriever API

Tags: android, android-sms

I've implemented the SMS Retriever API and seen some conflicting information on what the expected behavior is when using this flow.

Ideally:

- There would be no visible SMS notification that the user might think they need to act on
- The SMS would not persist in the messages app

Is it possible to achieve this experience?

Reference: https://medium.com/@petar.marijanovic/sms-verification-on-android-534959588a1e

> Also, when the device receives the SMS message, no notification is triggered and the SMS can’t be found in the devices SMS app. By doing that, Android Oreo improved the security of user data because no other application will be able to read the content.

Comment: I've the same problem, it's really annoying